# EF Core 6 - QueryBody must end with a Select clause or Group clause

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have this rather verbose LINQ query the returns an intellisense error:

> Query Body Must End With A Select Clause or Group Clause

It looks like it does so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. It appears I am doing a select at the end, but apparently that's now a correct Select?

I'm new to linq so be gentle. Granted this is a long query with some important business logic. I'm on a tight deadline so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```cs
var data =
    (from cm in ctx.CommitteeMemberships.Include(ct => ct.Term)

    .Where(
                cm =>
                cm.PartitionKey == controllerStateManager.PartitionKey &&
                cm.CommitteeId == committeeId &&
                // (p.EffectiveStartDate >= effectiveDateStart 
                (
                (
                    (cm.StartDate != null ? cm.StartDate >= effectiveDateStart : cm.Term != null && cm.Term.StartDate >= effectiveDateStart) &&
                    //&& p.EffectiveStartDate <= effectiveDateEnd) ||
                    (cm.StartDate != null ? cm.StartDate <= effectiveDateEnd : cm.Term != null && cm.Term.StartDate <= effectiveDateEnd)
                )
                ||

                // (p.EffectiveEndDate >= effectiveDateStart 
                (
                    (cm.EndDate != null ? effectiveDateStart >= cm.EndDate : cm.Term != null && cm.Term.EndDate >= effectiveDateStart) &&
                    // && p.EffectiveEndDate <= effectiveDateEnd) ||
                    (cm.EndDate != null ? cm.EndDate <= effectiveDateEnd : cm.Term != null && cm.Term.EndDate <= effectiveDateEnd)
                )
                ||
                (
                    // (effectiveDateStart >= p.EffectiveStartDate 
                    (effectiveDateStart >= (cm.StartDate != null ? cm.StartDate : cm.Term != null ? cm.Term.StartDate : cm.StartDate)) &&
                    // && effectiveDateStart <= p.EffectiveEndDate) ||
                    (effectiveDateStart <= (cm.EndDate != null ? cm.EndDate : cm.Term != null ? cm.Term.EndDate : cm.EndDate))
                )
                ||
                (
                    //(effectiveDateEnd >= p.EffectiveStartDate 
                    (effectiveDateEnd >= (cm.StartDate != null ? cm.StartDate : cm.Term != null ? cm.Term.StartDate : cm.StartDate)) &&
                    // && effectiveDateEnd <= p.EffectiveEndDate)
                    (effectiveDateEnd <= (cm.EndDate != null ? cm.EndDate : cm.Term != null ? cm.Term.EndDate : cm.EndDate))
                )
                )
            )

    .Skip((pageFilter.PageNumber - 1) * pageFilter.PageSize).Take(pageFilter.PageSize)

        .Select(cm =>
                new CommitteeMembershipDto
                {
                    Row = cm.Row,
                    Id = cm.Id,
                    PartitionKey = cm.PartitionKey,
                    Name = cm.Name,
                    Type = cm.Type,
                    CommitteeId = cm.CommitteeId,
                    MemberId = cm.MemberId,
                    TermId = cm.TermId,
                    PositionId = cm.PositionId,
                    StartDate = cm.StartDate,
                    EndDate = cm.EndDate,
                    Notes = cm.Notes,
                    Keywords = cm.Keywords,
                    SecurityLock = cm.SecurityLock,
                    LockedForDeletion = cm.LockedForDeletion,
                    IsConfiguration = cm.IsConfiguration,
                    IsSealed = cm.IsSealed,
                    LastModifiedById = cm.LastModifiedById,
                    LastModifiedDate = cm.LastModifiedDate,
                    CreatedById = cm.CreatedById,
                    CreatedDate = cm.CreatedDate,
                    SystemTimestamp = cm.SystemTimestamp,
                    GrantPortalAdministratorPrivileges = cm.GrantPortalAdministratorPrivileges,
                    CreatedByName = cm.CreatedByName,
                    LastModifiedByName = cm.LastModifiedByName,
                    EffectiveStartDate = cm.Term != null ? cm.Term.StartDate : (cm.StartDate != null) ? cm.StartDate : new DateTime(1900, 1, 1),
                    EffectiveEndDate = cm.Term != null ? cm.Term.EndDate : (cm.EndDate != null) ? cm.EndDate : new DateTime(9999, 1, 1)
                }
            )
        );
```

Comment: Replace `(from cm in ctx.CommitteeMemberships.Include(ct => ct.Term)` with `ctx.CommitteeMemberships.Include(ct => ct.Term)`, Or add `select` to the end `(from cm in ctx.CommitteeMemberships.Include(ct => ct.Term) select cm`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your query is that you have an extra dot (".") after the CommitteeMemberships.Include(ct => ct.Term) line, which is causing the error. Here's the corrected query:

```
var data =
    (from cm in ctx.CommitteeMemberships.Include(ct => ct.Term)
     where
         cm.PartitionKey == controllerStateManager.PartitionKey &&
         cm.CommitteeId == committeeId &&
         // (p.EffectiveStartDate >= effectiveDateStart 
         (
             (
                 (cm.StartDate != null ? cm.StartDate >= effectiveDateStart : cm.Term != null && cm.Term.StartDate >= effectiveDateStart) &&
                 //&& p.EffectiveStartDate <= effectiveDateEnd) ||
                 (cm.StartDate != null ? cm.StartDate <= effectiveDateEnd : cm.Term != null && cm.Term.StartDate <= effectiveDateEnd)
             )
             ||

             // (p.EffectiveEndDate >= effectiveDateStart 
             (
                 (cm.EndDate != null ? effectiveDateStart >= cm.EndDate : cm.Term != null && cm.Term.EndDate >= effectiveDateStart) &&
                 // && p.EffectiveEndDate <= effectiveDateEnd) ||
                 (cm.EndDate != null ? cm.EndDate <= effectiveDateEnd : cm.Term != null && cm.Term.EndDate <= effectiveDateEnd)
             )
             ||
             (
                 // (effectiveDateStart >= p.EffectiveStartDate 
                 (effectiveDateStart >= (cm.StartDate != null ? cm.StartDate : cm.Term != null ? cm.Term.StartDate : cm.StartDate)) &&
                 // && effectiveDateStart <= p.EffectiveEndDate) ||
                 (effectiveDateStart <= (cm.EndDate != null ? cm.EndDate : cm.Term != null ? cm.Term.EndDate : cm.EndDate))
             )
             ||
             (
                 //(effectiveDateEnd >= p.EffectiveStartDate 
                 (effectiveDateEnd >= (cm.StartDate != null ? cm.StartDate : cm.Term != null ? cm.Term.StartDate : cm.StartDate)) &&
                 // && effectiveDateEnd <= p.EffectiveEndDate)
                 (effectiveDateEnd <= (cm.EndDate != null ? cm.EndDate : cm.Term != null ? cm.Term.EndDate : cm.EndDate))
             )
         )
     )
     .Skip((pageFilter.PageNumber - 1) * pageFilter.PageSize)
     .Take(pageFilter.PageSize)
     .Select(cm =>
         new CommitteeMembershipDto
         {
             Row = cm.Row,
             Id = cm.Id,
             PartitionKey = cm.PartitionKey,
             Name = cm.Name,
             Type = cm.Type,
             CommitteeId = cm.CommitteeId,
             MemberId = cm.MemberId,
             TermId = cm.TermId,
             PositionId = cm.PositionId,
             StartDate = cm.StartDate,
             EndDate = cm.EndDate,
             Notes = cm.Notes,
             Keywords = cm.Keywords,
             SecurityLock = cm.SecurityLock,
             LockedForDeletion = cm.LockedForDeletion,
             IsConfiguration = cm.IsConfiguration,
             IsSealed = cm.IsSealed,
             LastModifiedById = cm.LastModifiedById,
             LastModifiedDate = cm.LastModifiedDate,
             CreatedById = cm.CreatedById,
             CreatedDate = cm.CreatedDate,
             SystemTimestamp = cm.SystemTimestamp,
             GrantPortalAdministratorPrivileges = cm.GrantPortalAdministratorPrivileges,
             CreatedByName = cm.CreatedByName,
             LastModifiedByName = cm.LastModifiedByName,
             EffectiveStartDate = cm.Term != null ? cm.Term.StartDate : (cm.StartDate != null) ? cm.StartDate : new DateTime(1900, 1, 1),
             EffectiveEndDate = cm.Term != null ? cm.Term.EndDate : (cm.EndDate != null
})
```